# With pydrive, sendNotificationEmails = False not working

Tags: python, pydrive

We are already successfully authenticated. We have the following python function using `PyDrive`:

```
def upload_to_drive(local_filepath):

    gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': '123ourdrivefolderid456'}]})
    gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
    gfile.Upload() # Upload the file.

    permission = gfile.InsertPermission({ 
        'type': 'user',
        'value': 'myemail@gmail.com',
        'role': 'reader'
    }, sendNotificationEmails = False)
    
    print(gfile['alternateLink'])
```

We receive the error `TypeError: InsertPermission() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sendNotificationEmails'`. We have `pydrive-1.3.1`. Other sources online indicated that passing the 2nd parameter `sendNotificationEmails = False` should work, but it is not. We've also tried `{ 'sendNotificationEmails': 'False' }` as a 2nd parameter to no success...

Comment: Have you tried including `'sendNotificationEmails': False` in the first dict itself? This is a parameter used by the [permissions.insert API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert) and the PyDrive method isn't expecting a second parameter.

Comment: @shriakhilc Yes and it is not working. I've tried both that as well as with `sendNotificationEmail` not pluralized

Answer (score 1):

this is the original InsertPermission method in **files.py** from PyDrive package:

```
def InsertPermission(self, new_permission):
    """Insert a new permission. Re-fetches all permissions after call.

    :param new_permission: The new permission to insert, please see the
    official Google Drive API guide on permissions.insert for details.

    :type new_permission: object

    :return: The permission object.
    :rtype: object
    """
    file_id = self.metadata.get('id') or self['id']
    try:
      permission = self.auth.service.permissions().insert(
        fileId=file_id, body=new_permission).execute(http=self.http)
    except errors.HttpError as error:
      raise ApiRequestError(error)
    else:
      self.GetPermissions()  # Update permissions field.

    return permission
```

it only accepts your permission dict

```
{
    'type': 'user',
    'value': 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'role': 'reader'
}
```

as the body of API requests (and no other arguments accepted as parameters).

while according to [Google Drive API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert), the *sendNotificationEmails* is a query parameter that you can not
find it in PyDrive's InsertPermission method.

To temporarily fix this problem I would suggest adding this parameter in the InsertPermission method and manually setting a
*sendNotificationEmails* parameter that is used from Google Drive API in **files.py** of the PyDrive package.

```
def InsertPermission(self, new_permission, sendNotificationEmails: bool = True):
    """Insert a new permission. Re-fetches all permissions after call.

    :param new_permission: The new permission to insert, please see the
    official Google Drive API guide on permissions.insert for details.

    :type new_permission: object

    :return: The permission object.
    :rtype: object
    """
    file_id = self.metadata.get('id') or self['id']
    try:
        permission = self.auth.service.permissions().insert(
            fileId=file_id, body=new_permission, sendNotificationEmails=sendNotificationEmails).execute(
            http=self.http)
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        raise ApiRequestError(error)
    else:
        self.GetPermissions()  # Update permissions field.

    return permission
```

Or you can try to replace your codes from PyDrive with codes from Google Drive documentation. In this case, you would be
easier to find why the error occurred, and always has detailed documentation that you could refer to.

Hope it helps you.